# How do I make a span go to the left of a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Inside the "main" div i have a bunch of spans and inputs. I want these to go to the very left of the main div, paralell to eachother. They structered in a way so that there is little question (the span) and under every question there is an answer section (inputs) and as I said I want these to the very left of the main div over and under eachother. How do I do this?

Here's the code:

```css
html,body{
  height:100%;
}

*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
.wraper{
  height:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.top {
  top:0;
  height: 92px;
  background:red;
}
.left {
  width: 178px;
  float:left;
  min-height:100%;
  background:#96C0CE;
}
.main {
  margin-left:178px;
  min-height:100%;
  background:#525564;
}
.space { 
  margin-top: 70px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="wraper">
  <div class="top">
    <center><h1 style="color:white">Header</h1></center>
  </div>

  <div class="left">
    <span> Hello </span>
    AND ALOT MORE SPANS!!!
    <input/>
    AND ALOT MORE INPUTS
  </div>
  <div class="main">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Side note: Your closing head tag is in the wrong place. Also, don't use the `<center>` element, it was removed in HTML5 and deprecated in 4.

Comment: and input don't have closing tag `</input>` it's self closing tag `<input/>` and doctype need exlamation mark.

Comment: Minor: [The **Alot** is better than you at everything](http://hyperboleandahalf.blogspot.com/2010/04/alot-is-better-than-you-at-everything.html)

Comment: You really should clean up your code before submitting it like this because what you're asking doesn't relate to the fact that your HTML is inconsistent; i.e. failure to close tags in the right spot.

Comment: Doesn't it work just by intercalating spans and inputs? [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nph02gqq/)

Comment: omit </input>; <input> doesn't need a closing tag

Comment: Sorry for all the mistakes, this isn't the real code its just somethign i put together in 2 minutes which is supposed to represent the code.

Comment: @EmilJohansson Get a working example in JSFiddle so we can answer your question

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs reviewed and made correct before it can be directly answered, so I'll answer your question.

*How do I make a span go to the left of a div?*

By using

```
float:left;
```

which will shift to the left of the direct parent encapsulating it.

https://jsfiddle.net/9urk5rzd/1/

Answer (score 0):

#### Hey... Just do this, *it's very simple!*

I think you mean it

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="copy.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="wraper">  
          <div class="top">
          <center><h1 style="color: white;">Header</h1></center>
          </div>
        </div>             <!-- close this div please like i did  -->
        <div class="left">
           <form name='myform' id='myform'>
             <span>Question </span>
             <br/><!-- br/ is used break the line -->
             <input name="a1" id='a1'type="text" placeholder="answer" > 
             <br/>
             <span>Question </span>
             <br/>
             <input name="a2" id='a2' type="text" placeholder="answer" > 
             <br/>
             <span>Question </span>
             <br/>
             <input name="a3" id='a3' type="text" placeholder="answer" > 
             <br/>
             <span>Question </span>
             <br/>
             <input name="a4" id='a4' type="text" placeholder="answer"><!-- remove the close from the inputs like i did -->
           </form>
        </div>
        <div class="main">
          some content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

#### okay now the css:

---

```
html,body{
height:100%; /* you don't need this REMOVE*/
}

*{
margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
body{
 background-color: green;/* I like green xD (put ur colors in hexa(for the browser compatibility(IE hates u and me)))*/


}
.wraper{
height:100%;
/*Stack*/ overflow:hidden;
}
.top {
  top:0; /* hum... ??*/
  height: 92px;
  background:red;
}
.left {
  width: 15%; /* ajust this as u want */
  float:left;
  min-height:100%; /* okay... */
  background:#96C0CE;
}
.main {
  margin-left:15%;
  height: 610px; /* adjust this as u need */
  background:#525564;
  width: 85%; /* if u adjust .left is recomendable to adjust .main too*/
}



.space { margin-top: 70px; }
```

Comment: is only necessary interim them, each input or spam put a <br/>